# Managing the files and extensions of a website

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

I am new to websites programming, to this point I only programmed desktop apps, And now I need to program a website at a training, after I started I fell into a mess as I used JavaScript, CSS, JSON, Bootstrap, Ajax, PHP and I got pretty confused while using all these extensions and
programming languages used together. how do you manage using all these things together and not get confused? Is there a certain way to do that simplifies the process?

Answer (score 1):

My advice is to **first** learn the languages.

- Learn HTML, not Bootstrap
- Learn CSS, not Tailwind
- Learn Javascript, not React
- Learn PHP, not Laravel or Wordpress

Once you have these the core languages understood, then you can focus on the niches, like React, Angular, etc, what ever your client or company requires from you.

The benefit of doing it this way is that you don't become overwhelmed. You understand how the stack works and then it's easier to understand how certain frameworks are different.

Answer (score 0):

Today, each of these languages and technologies are specialized areas, and usually, a specialist is considered for them in projects.
But to manage them properly and not to be confused, there are many ways such as using different architectures and design systems such as Atomic Design System, MVC, etc. that you can learn from them depending on your type of work and Use in the project